# Pasar Usuario, contraseña y JSON por parametro en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, nodejs

Necesito pasar la contraseña, el usuario y un JSON por parametro. En este momento tengo 2 metodos que uno recibe la contraseña y el usuario y el otro recibe el JSON, pero necesito que un solo metodo reciba los 3 parametros.

Estos son los datos que le paso cuando pido el usuario y la contraseña:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo para obtener el usuario y la contraseña:

```
router.post('/api/v1/Login', jsonParser, function(req, res){
  if(!req.body)
  return res.sendStatus(400)
  console.log(req.body);

  var UsuarioReg = req.body.user;
  var ContraReg = req.body.pass;

  console.log("User: "+UsuarioReg + " Contraseña: "+ContraReg)
});
```

En la otra ruta le paso este JSON:

```
[{
    "Notification": [{
            "Channel": 1,
            "Type": 1,
            "Means": [{
                "Number": 88888888,
                "Code": 506
            }],
            "Contents": {
                "Message": "This is a message"
            }
        }
    ]
}]
```

Esta es el código que utilizo para obtener el JSON:

```
router.post('/api/v1/Validation', function(request, res){
   var jsonDa = request.body;
   var fine = 0;
)
```

A mi me gustaria algo asi:

```
router.post('api/v1/ejemplo', function(req,res){
var user = request.body.user;
var pass = request.body.pass;
var json = request.body.json;


console.log("User: "+user + " pass: "+pass)
console.log("JSON: "+json)
})
```

Si me podrian dar un ejemplo de como pasar toda la informacion por postman en un **"application/json raw"** Gracias!!!

Comment: ¿Esos parametros lo envias a algun api o servlet?

Comment: Podrías poner que intentas o un ejemplo?. No termino de entender que quieres hacer, porque con un `Post()`  podrías enviar _usuario_, _contraseña_ y el JSON en el _body_ y recibirlo en un solo metodo.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con @Federico, pon un ejemplo o un avance de lo que deseas lograr (aunque no funcione, solo a modo de ejemplo) ya que no queda muy claro lo que deseas ;)

Comment: He moddificado la pregunta y puse un ejemplo para ver si me entienden mejor :) Gracias!

Comment: Por lo que planteas, yo te diría que revises JWT. Enviarías la autenticación en la cabecera y el json con la info en el body correspondiente.

Answer (score 0):

Si deseas enviar en un solo json todas tus variables, debería quedar de la siguiente manera:

```
{
    "user": "usuario",
    "pass": "password",
    "json": [{
        "Notification": [{
            "Channel": 1,
            "Type": 1,
            "Means": [{
                "Number": 88888888,
                "Code": 506
            }],
            "Contents": {
                "Message": "This is a message"
            }
        }]
    }]
}
```

De tal forma que puedas acceder a las propiedades de la siguiente manera:

```js
var request = '{ "user": "usuario", "pass": "password", "json": [{ "Notification": [{ "Channel": 1, "Type": 1, "Means": [{ "Number": 88888888, "Code": 506 }], "Contents": { "Message": "This is a message" }}]}] }';

//Esto es a modo de ejemplo ya que el back-end realiza de manera automática el parseo de la petición
var body = JSON.parse(request);

console.log(body.user);
console.log(body.pass);
console.log(body.json);
console.log(body.json[0].Notification[0].Channel);
```

Comment: @java005 ¿fue de utilidad la respuesta?